# getting indexes of smallest items in the presence of NA

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I need to get the indices of the DataFrame of the smallest `n` items, ignoring NAs. If I didn't have NAs, I'd do this:

```
s = pd.Series([4,3,1,5,2], index=range(10,15))
idx = s.argsort()[:2]
# check:
s.iloc[idx] # [1, 2] as desired
```

But in the presence of NA, this won't work:

```
s = pd.Series([None,3,1,5,2], index=range(10,15))
idx = s.argsort()[:2]
# check:
s.iloc[idx] # [2.0, 3.0] instead of [1.0, 2.0]
```

This is because `arg_sort` (unlike `sort_values`) simply skips NA completely, and doesn't include them in the count. Is there any function that behaves like `arg_sort` but places NA at the end? Or alternatively, what's the best way to rewrite the above code to work with NA?

I guess I could `drop_na()` every time before I do this, but this will be done for multiple columns in a dataframe, so it seems inefficient to make another pass for every column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC, you can use [nsmallest](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.nsmallest.html#pandas.Series.nsmallest), to get the indices corresponding to the amount of smallest values desired:

```
In [2]: s = pd.Series([4,3,1,5,2], index=range(10,15))

In [3]: a = s.nsmallest(2)

In [4]: a
Out[4]: 
12    1
14    2
dtype: int64

In [5]: s = pd.Series([None,3,1,5,2], index=range(10,15))

In [6]: a = s.nsmallest(2)

In [7]: a
Out[7]: 
12    1.0
14    2.0
dtype: float64
```

Comment: Ah... I forgot `nsmallest` keeps the indices too.

Answer (score 2):

IIUC you could use [`sort_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.sort_values.html):

```
s = pd.Series([None,3,1,5,2], index=range(10,15))

In [140]: s.sort_values()[:2]
Out[140]: 
12    1.0
14    2.0
dtype: float64
```

For first scenario

```
s = pd.Series([4,3,1,5,2], index=range(10,15))

In [142]: s.sort_values()[:2]
Out[142]: 
12    1
14    2
dtype: int64
```

**Timing:**

```
In [143]: %timeit s.sort_values()[:2]
1000 loops, best of 3: 349 µs per loop

In [144]: %timeit s.nsmallest(2)
1000 loops, best of 3: 370 µs per loop
```

If you need indices for that values you could use `index` attribute:

```
In [145]: s.sort_values()[:2].index
Out[145]: Int64Index([12, 14], dtype='int64')
```

**EDIT**

For big series `nsmallest` works faster:

```
s = pd.Series(np.random.random(size=100000))

In [16]: %timeit s.nsmallest(2)
100 loops, best of 3: 2.5 ms per loop

In [17]: %timeit s.sort_values()[:2]
100 loops, best of 3: 12.4 ms per loop
```

Comment: Wouldn't `nsmallest` be much faster only on large datasets?